# Python module visiable only in iPython

Tags: python, scope, ipython

I have used `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;dictionary_containing_modules` to make some modules globaly visiable.

I have a script importing the modules with `import my_module`.

When i run the script from the iPython shell (`run my_script.py`), i get no errors and the script runs as intended, but when I run the script from the command promt (windows) with `python my_script.py` I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named my_module
```

I checked with `pwd` that they use the same working directory.

Comment: What does display `echo %PYTHONPATH%` from the command-prompt you run the script?

Comment: `echo %PYTHONPATH%"` returns `%PYTHONPATH%`. Oh yeah, that seems wrong.

Comment: ...and in iPython `echo %PYTHONPATH%` returns the proper paths..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you can dynamically change your system path from within your script, using [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) or the [`site` module](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html). So maybe you want to add them to your script...

Or maybe you want to write a BAT or Python launcher script that sets the PYTHONPATH...

Or you want to edit the Windows environment variables (somewhere inside System properties <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>).